Extract intents from a conversations/transcripts data dump in unsupervised mode
I want to develop a tool that will take a bunch of conversation texts from call centers (between agents and users) and be able to build a multi-intent hierarchical structure based on the input data fed. I am not sure on where and how to approach this problem. If anyone can shed some light and share some samples or code references that I can further study and extend, that will be greatly helpful. After analyzing all the conversations, I must construct the intent list as below (given as an example)
{ "parent_intent": "Sales", "child_intent": [ "Add Service Features", "subchild_intent": [......], ...... ..... ....
}
